# What is the advantage of having multiple remote terminal (RTs) in 1553B terminal?

Tags: spi, interface, aviation-electronics, mil-std-1553

I have been trying to understand the difference between 1553B terminals with single and dual Remote Terminals (RTs). I have given 2 links below for the references:

[link 1](http://www.holtic.com/products/3102-hi-6138.aspx): Single RT

[link 2](http://www.holtic.com/products/3066-hi-2130.aspx): Dual RT

How this extra independent remote terminal will help to connect an extra sub-system.

In the following figure, when the Bus Controller BC (Mission Computer) switch to the Remote Terminal, how it will be helpful if there are two independent Remote Terminals available? Is if for connecting multiple sub-systems through SPI interface?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I also wondering that ...